# Expression "only that/so a moment later..."

Tags: idioms, conjunctions

Despite my online research, I can't decide whether the expression "..only that/so a moment later..." actually exists. (I use the "/" slash sign because I can't decide that even if the expression exists, whether it's with "that" or "so".)

For example: "He cleaned the kitchen, *only that/so a moment later* his sister would walk in and make a mess again."

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One related idiom is ***only to (do something)***:

> An expression used *to highlight an upsetting, disappointing, or otherwise unpleasant action that occurred immediately after something else*.
>
> - I worked on that proposal for over a month, ***only to find*** that they had awarded the contract to the firm across town.
> - It can be disheartening to spend a lot of time preparing a meal ***only to** have your kids turn their nose up at it*. ([freedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/only+to))

So your sentence could be:

> He cleaned the kitchen, ***only to have his sister walk in*** (a moment later) and make a mess again.

Comment: Note that there are very specific uses for _find_ and _have_ in this idiom, depending on what happens.

Comment: Or **only for his sister to walk in...**

Comment: @Kate Again, an answer, probably the optimal one. [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/only-for) and ELL are useful sources.

Comment: only to find, only to have, only to see, only to hear, only to get, etc. The usage is not limited to find and have and others. The semantics have to point to an unexpected outcome in terms of the antecedent phrase.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither of those is really idiomatic. The expression you may be looking for is **only for his sister to walk in**, meaning that the thing that happened made someone's previous work a waste of time.

See [this from ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198524/can-only-for-mean-instead)

Comment: All of the above, in my experience (in the US).  I don't see anything wrong with "only to have/see/etc."

Comment: @aparente001 - I meant that the two versions mentioned in the question, 'only that' and 'only so', were not idiomatic. Edwin suggested that I make my comment into an answer, so I did.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. / But note, I don't find your reference Q-A at ELL particularly helpful here.

Comment: @aparente001 -In their answer, J.Taylor said _The phrase "only for", when used in this manner, is generally there to emphasize that someone expended a lot of energy/effort on something, but that unexpected events ended up making their efforts useless or unnecessary._ That seems to me to fit the situation described by the OP.

Comment: Okay, I guess it supports your proposed expression.  Let me ask you explicitly -- what's your view about lambie's proposals?

Comment: @aparente001 - I agree with Lambie's comment that _only to_ + verb is fine.